# How to use Gitlab CI to deploy a Showoff application on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, gitlab

I have successfully deployed a showoff presentation on [Heroku](https://lunar-teach.herokuapp.com/). Because Heroku makes it so easy to integrate Github, I have also been able to add a [Github repository](https://github.com/githarkiratITP/lunar-teach) that auto-deploys on Heroku.

I want to setup the same thing in Gitlab. Can someone please help me in setting it up?

The `app.json` used by Github is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "lunar-teach",
  "scripts": {
  },
  "env": {
    "LANG": {
      "required": true
    },
    "RACK_ENV": {
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "formation": {
  },
  "addons": [

  ],
  "buildpacks": [
    {
      "url": "heroku/ruby"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `.gitlab-ci.yml` config:

> For this config to work, you need to get your [heroku API key](https://dashboard.heroku.com/account).

First define the stages you want to use, 
If you want to add testing to your CI pipeline, add it here:

```
stages:
  - staging
  - production
```

For each stage defined above, ensure you have a corresponding `heroku` app created, and that each `heroku` app has a `ruby` buildpack added.

Now, for some housekeeping, and ensuring everything's upto date

```
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
```

Now, for each of the stages you defined earlier, describe the ruby version you need.

> As of January 2017, `showoff` uses Ruby `v2.2.6`, update the image after checking the Ruby documentation

Add the `$HEROKU_APP-NAME` and the `$HEROKU_API_KEY` for each stage.

```
staging:
  image: ruby:2.2
  stage: staging
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP-NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY --strategy=git
  only:
    - staging

production:
  image: ruby:2.2
  stage: production
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-ruby-test-prod --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY --strategy=git
  only:
    - master
```

The complete script looks like this:

```
stages:
  - staging
  - production

before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy

staging:
  image: ruby:2.2
  stage: staging
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-ruby-test-prod --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY --strategy=git
  only:
    - staging

production:
  image: ruby:2.2
  stage: production
  script:
    - gem install dpl
    - dpl --provider=heroku --app=gitlab-ci-ruby-test-prod --api-key=$HEROKU_PRODUCTION_API_KEY --strategy=git
  only:
    - master
```